# Remove first occurrence of special characters until the first word or word character in R using regex

Tags: r, regex

For my project I am looking into removing parts of text based on the pattern of special characters. I have a long .txt file that has the below structure:

```
mycharobj=c("---------Some text is here.---------More text is here - [3548]----- Even more text is here.-----------More text is here - [408]--------- Even more text is here again.")
```

String continues following the above pattern.

My target is to remove parts that start with `- and end - [number]`, such as:

```
"-----------------------More text is here - [3548]"
"-----------More text is here - [408]"
```

I am planning to use the below to remove these parts with (will be looped in the future)

```
library(stringr)
library(qdapRegex)

temp=unlist(regmatches(mycharobj, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+", mycharobj)))
mycharobj=rm_between(mycharobj, "-", paste(temp[1],"]", sep=""))
```

but for this to work, I need a regex expression that will remove the first occurrence of `"-----------"` in text until the first word or word character. If a string starts with text (word or word characters), it needs to ignore this and identify the first occurrence of `"-----------"` for my potential loop to work.

I was wondering if this can be done with regular expressions? Any help is appreciated. I have a very computationally demanding solution for this; split the string based on the special character "-" and then identify the parts of the text that I need through a set of conditionals. But due to the fact that it takes a lot more of the processing time, this solution is not very scalable for processing a large number of such .txt files.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Something like this: "---------Some text is here.----- Even more text is here.-----------Even more text is here again."

Comment: Try `gsub("-{9,}\\W*((?:(?!-{9}).)*?)- \\[\\d+]", " \\1", mycharobj, perl=TRUE)`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ndD6rU/2).

Comment: Many thanks! Does the trick for the above, but if the part I am looking to remove contains a ";" or other special character as "-----------------------More text; is here - [3548]", it does not work for my file unfortunately.

Comment: So, `gsub("-{9,}(?:(?!-{9}).)*?- \\[\\d+]", "", mycharobj, perl=TRUE)`? See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ndD6rU/3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```r
gsub("-{9,}(?:(?!-{9}).)*?- \\[\\d+]", "", mycharobj, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ndD6rU/3).

*Details*:

- `-{9,}` - nine or more `-` chars
- `(?:(?!-{9}).)*?` - any one char, other than a line break char, zero or more but as few as possible occurrences, that does not start a nine hyphen char sequence
- `- \[` - a `- [` string
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `]` - a `]` char.